# How to programatically make a key shortcut?

Tags: macos, bash, task-switching

I'm not even sure if bash is the most proper way to achieve this but, I need to, programmatically, switch between opened applications on OS X.

I'm thinking about doing a bash program to execute "cmd+tab".

I'm unable to find this on a regular search, so, perhaps someone can point me some directions here?

Comment: I don't think you really want to tab to "the" next program – even doing this manually, I often have to repeat to get the one I *meant*. Are you sure you don't mean "programmatically *activate* one of my opened applications" instead?

Comment: This is for a kiosk like application. I will have only two windows opened. One is the browser, and the other is a Mac OS X app. I wish to programmatically switch between them. So, I thought that simply emulate "cmd+tab" would be enough, since no other apps will be opened, and I can set the "first" application to appear, and then, it will be like a switch.

Comment: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Applescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) to achieve this.

To focus on a specific application:

```
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

And to emulate an actual Cmd+Tab input:

```
tell application "System Events"
  key down command
  keystroke tab
  key up command
end tell
```

Applescript files (*.scpt) can be run through the command line with `osascript file.scpt`.